# How can i check if my bot have specified permissions on guild?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am checking if user have kick permission with the following code:

```
if (!message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    return;
}
```

But how can i check if my bot have permissions for kick members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to check if the bot can kick someone you should use `<memberToKick>.kickable` should return true/false if the bot can kick or not that member.
But to check if the bot has any permission, `guild.me` returns the guildMember of the bot, so `guild.me.hasPermission("")`.